# Auto indent Javascript code in Emacs (bsd style aka Allman style)

Tags: javascript, emacs, indentation, auto-indent

I can't set Emacs to work with Javascript. I want Emacs makes auto indent, when I press "{" and "}". When I write code on C, it works very well. When I press "}" the parenthesis tooks its place.
I'd like to see something like this:

[very good styles](http://upload.akusherstvo.ru/image1311248.png)

But I get this:

[it's my problem here](http://upload.akusherstvo.ru/image1311249.png)

I don't understand why parenthesis remain in place.

Could you tell me, what should I do to make it right, please?

I think, I need to add something to my .emacs file, aren't I?

Here is my .emacs:

```
(setq c-default-style "bsd" 
      c-basic-offset 4)
(setq-default c-basic-offset 4
              tab-width 4
              indent-tabs-mode nil)

(setq make-backup-files nil
      auto-save-default nil
      auto-save-list-file-name nil)


(global-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)                           

(show-paren-mode t) ; Highlight expression between {}, (), []
(setq show-paren-style 'parenthesis) ; parenthesis | expression | mixed

(add-hook 'html-mode-hook
            (lambda ()
                  ;; Default indentation is usually 2 spaces, changing to 4.
                  (set (make-local-variable 'sgml-basic-offset) 2)
                  (setq tab-width 2)
            )
)

(setq font-lock-maximum-decoration
      '((html-mode . 1)))

(setq column-number-mode t)

;(electric-pair-mode t)
;(setq electric-pair-preserve-balance nil)
;(electric-indent-mode -1)


; 80 letters rule (highlight)
(setq-default
  whitespace-line-column 78
   whitespace-style       '(face lines-tail))
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'whitespace-mode) ; only if I write code
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook #'whitespace-mode) ; and the other cases

; Use all c-mode settings when I code on javascript (indent, tab-width, ...)
;(add-hook 'js-mode-hook 'c-mode)

;(add-hook 'js-mode-hook #'c-default-style)

;(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.js\\'" . c-mode))
```

Comment: Do you use the built-in js-mode or [other js modes](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/JavaScript) ?

Comment: I'd say your line `(global-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)` might be problematic. Can you try without ? (and afterwards, with `indent-according-to-mode` ?)

Comment: Built-in js-mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any built-in functions or ready-made solution, so I read emacs documentation and wrote my own emacs-lisp function. Maybe someone will need it.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)

(add-hook 'js-mode-hook
    (lambda()
        (local-set-key (kbd "{")
            (lambda() (interactive)
                (my-bsd-lparen-align)
                (insert "{")
            )
        )
        (local-set-key (kbd "}")
            (lambda() (interactive)
                (insert "}")
                (indent-according-to-mode)
                ;(c-indent-command)                                             
            )
        )
    )
)


(defun my-bsd-lparen-align()
    (skip-chars-forward " \t")
    (setq cur_pos (point))
    (my-line-begin)
    (setq new_pos (point))
    (goto-char cur_pos)
    (if (eq cur_pos new_pos)
        (__my-bsd-lparen-put)
    )
)

(defun my-line-begin()
    (beginning-of-line)
    (skip-chars-forward " \t")
    (current-column)
)

(defun __my-bsd-lparen-put()
    (setq init_pos (point))
    (setq cur_start (my-line-begin))
    (forward-line -1)
    (setq block_start (my-line-begin))
    (setq diff (- cur_start block_start))
    (goto-char init_pos)
    (if (>= diff 0)
        (delete-backward-char diff)
        (loop for i from 1 to (- diff) do (insert " "))
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try js2-mode. That has better style and indentation.
BTW you should probably not write everything in the .emacs like this. 
The file structure could be something like

```
|.emacs
| -- <your mode files.el>
```

I have my own .emacs and the helper files here:

```
https://bitbucket.org/tdatta/ansible_plays
```

its under

```
roles--> emacs --> files
```

you can have have a look at  one for reference. It's not perfect but still better structured.

Comment: I tried. The same result. More paintful highlighting but parenthisis don't move.

Comment: Hmm not sure why you would have that. I tried it in both windows and linux and seems to be working fine. If you can provide more information (Version of emacs + platform) and link your your .emacs  then it would be easier for anyone to provide you concrete answer.